# tikz: text in rectangular split inside matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, matrices

I have a `tikz` `matrix`, some of those cells are of shape rectangle split, how do I set text in both parts of the `rectangle split`?

Here is a MWE. I would like to have text in both parts of the rectangular split ...

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}   % \text nas equacoes
\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=1.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.0cm,bindingoffset=-1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,matrix,fit,shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
    status/.style={draw=black, minimum width=2em, minimum height=2em, text=gray, anchor=center},
    mstyle/.style={nodes={status}, column sep=0.12em, row sep=0.12em},
    splitstyle/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal, rectangle split parts=2, rectangle split every empty part={}, rectangle split empty part width={0.3em}, anchor=center},
    line/.style={draw,ultra thick,-latex},
    row 2 column 2/.style={nodes={fill=green}},
    row 1 column 3/.style={nodes={splitstyle, rectangle split part fill={green,orange}}},
    row 2 column 3/.style={nodes={fill=green}},
    row 4 column 2/.style={nodes={splitstyle, rectangle split part fill={red,green}}},
    row 3 column 6/.style={nodes={fill=green}},
    row 4 column 3/.style={nodes={fill=orange}},
    row 4 column 5/.style={nodes={fill=orange}},
    row 3 column 4/.style={nodes={fill=red}},
    row 1 column 6/.style={nodes={fill=red}},
}
\matrix(m)[matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&,mstyle]{
    0 \& 0 \& {} \& 0 \& 0 \& 3 \\
    0 \& 4 \& 5 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \\
    0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 6 \& 0 \& 7 \\
    0 \& 8 \& 10 \& 0 \& 11 \& 0 \\
};
\draw[line] (m-4-5.center) -- (m-3-4.center);
\draw[line] (m-1-6.center) -- (m-3-6.center);
\draw[line] (m-2-2.center) -- (m-4-1.center);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Just to make it clear. I would like to add text where the red circles are. Can I using this matrix approach?

[image: mockup]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to apply the split directly inside the node.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,matrix,fit,shapes,backgrounds}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
    status/.style={draw=black, minimum width=2em, minimum height=2em, text=gray, anchor=center},
    mstyle/.style={nodes={status}, column sep=0.12em, row sep=0.12em},
    splitstyle/.style={inner sep=0.23em,rectangle split, rectangle split horizontal, rectangle split parts=2,rectangle split every empty part={}, rectangle split empty part width={0.3em},  anchor=center},
    line/.style={draw,ultra thick,-latex},
    row 2 column 2/.style={nodes={fill=green}},
    %row 1 column 3/.style={nodes={splitstyle, rectangle split part fill={green,orange}}},
    row 2 column 3/.style={nodes={fill=green}},
    %row 4 column 2/.style={nodes={splitstyle, rectangle split part fill={red,green}}},
    row 3 column 6/.style={nodes={fill=green}},
    row 4 column 3/.style={nodes={fill=orange}},
    row 4 column 5/.style={nodes={fill=orange}},
    row 3 column 4/.style={nodes={fill=red}},
    row 1 column 6/.style={nodes={fill=red}},
}
\matrix(m)[matrix of nodes,ampersand replacement=\&,mstyle]{
    0 \& 0 \& |[splitstyle,rectangle split part fill={green,orange}]| 0\nodepart{two}8  \& 0 \& 0 \& 3 \\
    0 \& 4 \& 5 \& 0 \& 0 \& 0 \\
    0 \& 0 \& 0 \& 6 \& 0 \& 7 \\
    0 \& |[splitstyle,rectangle split part fill={orange,green}]| 8\nodepart{two}0 \& 10 \& 0 \& 11 \& 0 \\
};
\draw[line] (m-4-5.center) -- (m-3-4.center);
\draw[line] (m-1-6.center) -- (m-3-6.center);
\draw[line] (m-2-2.center) -- (m-4-1.center);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]