# Why is the style specifier appearing instead of the split rectangle in this matrix?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I'm creating a step-wise schematic of a process of re-linking a doubly linked lists. My intuition is to use split rectangles for the nodes (representing pointers and value, respectively), and then a matrix to arrange these rectangles.

Since the figure in the end will have many repeated arrows (and some that differ between rows, but that's a later problem), I'd like to use a matrix of nodes and the `M-i-j`-syntax. But, with this I cannot use the `nodes=somestyle` option of the matrix, at least not if I want different text in the split rectangles, as discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236800/tikz-text-in-rectangular-split-inside-matrix). It seems as if I'm deemed to use the syntax `|[stylename]|` before each node, but I get a rather odd behavior from the following MWE: the rectangle won't appear, instead the style-specifier (or what to call it) shows! Annoyingly, it only happens in the first column on row 2 and 3, but nowhere else. See included picture.

One simple solution is to just add an empty node in the beginning of each row (e.g. by adding `{} &` before A1, A2 and A3), but this seemsa bit stupid, and I'd like to understand what is going on instead.

What goes wrong here? Is there a better approach?

[image]

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart, matrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[triple/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3,
    draw, rectangle split horizontal, minimum size=5mm}]

\matrix (M) [matrix of nodes, row sep=0.5cm, column sep=0.5cm] {    
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} A1 &
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} B1 &
  {$\ldots$} &
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} C1 &
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} D1 &
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} E1 \\
  
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} A2 &
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} B2 &
  {$\ldots$} &
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} C2 &
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} D2 &
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} E2 \\
  
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} A3 &
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} B3 &
  {$\ldots$} &
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} C3 &
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} D3 &
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} E3 \\
  };

  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just remove (or comment out) the blank lines in the `\matrix` :-)

Guessing what happens: the Ti*k*Z `matrix` code scanning for the special `|...|` syntax at the start of an entry sees `\par` (generated from the blank line) and stops here, concluding there is no `|...|` in the cell. Then `|` gets typeset as cell contents and becomes “—” in the output because your document uses `OT1` font encoding (it is the default), and that's how it is in `OT1` (slot `"7C` is for the em dash, cf. `texdoc encguide` for [encguide.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/encguide.pdf), p. 19). With `T1` encoding, you would get a “|” in the output instead (`texdoc encguide` p. 22).

BTW, why char `"7C` from the current font? Because `|` has catcode 12 (this is standard), and its TeX-internal code (~ ASCII) is `"7C`.

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart, matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[triple/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3,
    draw, rectangle split horizontal, minimum size=5mm}]

\matrix (M) [matrix of nodes, row sep=0.5cm, column sep=0.5cm] {
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} A1 &
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} B1 &
  {$\ldots$} &
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} C1 &
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} D1 &
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} E1 \\
  % <----------------- Here
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} A2 &
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} B2 &
  {$\ldots$} &
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} C2 &
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} D2 &
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} E2 \\
  % <----------------- Here
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} A3 &
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} B3 &
  {$\ldots$} &
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} C3 &
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} D3 &
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} E3 \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

What [@frougon guesses](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/646984) is right: when `matrix of nodes` is used, the `\par` token is not ignored and stops the detection for `|`.

In example below, `\tikz@lib@matrix@start@cell` is patched so when a `\par` token is encountered, it's skipped (but not ignored) and the detection for `|` continues:

```tex
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart, matrix}

\makeatletter
% originally defined in tikzlibrarymatrix.code.tex
\def\tikz@lib@matrix@start@cell{%
  % skip possible \par
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar\par
    {\par\expandafter\tikz@lib@matrix@start@@cell\pgfutil@gobble}
    {\tikz@lib@matrix@start@@cell}%
}
\def\tikz@lib@matrix@start@@cell{%
  \pgfutil@ifnextchar|%
    {\tikz@lib@matrix@with@options}{\tikz@lib@matrix@normal@start@cell}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every label/.style={align=center, font=\scriptsize\ttfamily}]
  \matrix[label={normal\\ no blank line}] {
    \node{a}; & \node{b}; \\
    \node{c}; & \node{d}; \\
  };

  \matrix[label={normal\\ blank line}] at (2,0) {
    \node{a}; & \node{b}; \\

    \node{c}; & \node{d}; \\
  };

  \matrix[matrix of nodes, label={matrix of nodes\\ no blank line}] at (4,0) {
   |[red]| a & b \\
   |[red]| c & d \\
  };

  \matrix[matrix of nodes, label={matrix of nodes\\ blank line}] at (6,0) {
   |[red]| a & b \\
   
   |[red]| c & d \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[triple/.style={rectangle split, rectangle split parts=3,
    draw, rectangle split horizontal, minimum size=5mm}]

\matrix (M) [matrix of nodes, row sep=0.5cm, column sep=0.5cm] {    
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} A1 &
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} B1 &
  {$\ldots$} &
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} C1 &
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} D1 &
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} E1 \\
  
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} A2 &
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} B2 &
  {$\ldots$} &
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} C2 &
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} D2 &
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} E2 \\
  
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} A3 &
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} B3 &
  {$\ldots$} &
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} C3 &
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} D3 &
  |[triple]| \nodepart{two} E3 \\
  };
  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]